# Converting List<int> to List of complex type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Problem is simple and I am looking for a simple solution. I am having a class with single member like

```
public class Test
{
      public int TestInt{get; set; }
}

List <Test> intList = new List<Test>();
```

and a list like

```
List <int> lstNumber
```

I want to do something like

`intList = lstNumber` . ``

I know I can do it using foreach statement but wondering as the class is just having one member i.e. too integer, is there is anyway I can convert it directly by using something like Linq. I am just a beginner programmer in C# so would really appreciate any help

Comment: I verified that you cannot use `lstNumber.Cast<Test>()` even if you implement an explicit or implicit cast operator for Test that will convert an int to a Test. While the cast works in regular code, such as `(Test)3` it will not work with linq's Cast function. I think this might be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers is nice. Also you can try LINQ like this:

```
intList = (from o in lstNumber select new Test { TestInt = o }).ToList<Test>();
```

Comment: `from` and `in` are extra noise, they don't have to be here. Same goes for explicitly specifying generic argument for `ToList`.

Answer (score 6):

This should work. You can create a new instance of `Test` for each integer in `lstNumber`.

```
var intList = lstNumber.Select(x => new Test{ TestInt = x}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
intList = lstNumber.Select( i => new Test { TestInt = i } ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to do something like this

```
intList = lstNumber.Select(x=> new Test{TestInt=x}).ToList();
```

Comment: my guess is that its because @Grant Winney has exactly the same answer, but beat you to answer by 1 minute xD